# Error while resolving instance for class Koin

Tags: android, koin

Help solve the problem!(((I have 3 modules for DI. There is a retrofit object in natworkModule, all viewModels in viewModelModule, and all requests to the server in respositoryModule. I did everything according to the documentation, but I cannot find this error in Google. Thank you in advance!!! Sorry for my english!)

```
class App : Application(){

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin(this, listOf(natworkModule, viewModelModule,repositoryModule))
       }
    }


var natworkModule = module {

  single { createOkHttpClient() }
  single { createApiService<ApiService>(get () ,getProperty(SERVER_URL)) 

  }

}


const val SERVER_URL = "https://api.github.com/"

fun createOkHttpClient() : OkHttpClient{
   val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
   httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
   return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build()
   }

 inline fun <reified T> createApiService(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,  url: String): T {
   val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(LiveDataCallAdapterFactory()).build()
   return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
 }

var repositoryModule = module {
    factory<TestRepository> {
        TestRepositoryImpl(get())
    }

}

var viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel {
        TestViewModel(get())
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you declare the method startKoin()      ??? that error is necessary if you did not create that method anywhere! methods can't be accessed magically! pls let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @W.Seun it's an extension function provided by Koin. Op, can you please specify the error message you get? What is `TestViewModel`'s constructor signature?

Comment: Oo I see it's a dependency injection for kotlin users, well after checking their documentation I'm wondering if you should be able to parse multiple modules in inside the  startKoin(this, listOf(/*yourModule*/))   I will suggest you parse just one Module first because I'm not even sure if you can parse multiple modules, so it should look like this startKoin(this, listOf(natworkModule))   if this worked and you think you can still parse more module which I don't know, then you might want to watch out for the module that's cause the error, it's not the startKoin().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in this constant value ->
 SERVER_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
 Koin could not find it. Therefore there was an exception. Thanks to all!!!